# how to download pdf file in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to download the table as pdf to which i am showing in the view..
for that i use this code.

```
      public void pdf()
      {
          MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
          Document document = new Document();
          PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream).CloseStream = false;

          document.Open();

         document.Add(new Paragraph("msg"));
          document.Add(new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
          document.Close();

          byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
          workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
          workStream.Position = 0;
          Response.Buffer = true;

          Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + Server.HtmlEncode("doc.pdf"));
          Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/pdf";
          Response.BinaryWrite(byteInfo);
          //return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");
      }
```

but it is showing in pdf only "msg". bt i want to show table in pdf. how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Now you only print paragraph like because you invoke it   `document.Add(new Paragraph("msg"));`

Correct syntaxis to download PDF:

```
  public static void DownloadPDF(HttpResponse response,string fileRelativePath)
{
    try
    {
        string contentType = "";
        //Get the physical path to the file.
        string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileRelativePath);

        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(fileRelativePath).Split('.')[1].ToLower();

        if (fileExt == "pdf")
        {
            //Set the appropriate ContentType.
            contentType = "Application/pdf";
        }

        //Set the appropriate ContentType.
        response.ContentType = contentType;
        response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + (new FileInfo(fileRelativePath)).Name);

        //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
        response.WriteFile(FilePath);
        response.End();
    }
    catch
    {
       //To Do
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i have to change anything in view..becoz its does'n download any pdf..it's redirect me to downloadpdf page.that is blank

Comment: no it is redirect to page that is blank..its doesn download pdf